# JavaScript function call I need to get rid of quotes from a string parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have to do a translate function using a structure looking like:

```js
let dict = [
    {
        en: "moon",
        de: "der Mond",
        hu: "hold",
        rs: "mesec"
    },
    {
        en: "fox",
        de: "der Fuchs",
        hu: "róka",
        rs: "lisica"
    },
    {
        en: "girl",
        de: "das Mädchen",
        hu: "lány",
        rs: "devojka"
    }
];
```

My function is:

```js
function translate(word, from, to) {
    return dict.find(x => x.from == word).to
}
```

And how I have to call the function:

```js
translate("fox", "en", "hu")
```

My `from` and `to` parameters just don't want to work and givinig back undifined. If I call it directly like:
`dict.find(x => x.en == "fox").hu`
it gives me the right value, which is "róka".
I figured out maybe it's because of the quotes but I didn't find any solution anywhere.

Comment: When using a variable to access an object property you need to use bracket notation, so `dict.find(x => x[from] == word)[to]` see: [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#syntax)

Comment: Have a look at [*property accessors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

Comment: depending on how big your dictionary is and how often you have to search there, it may be worth to use this format: `var dict2 = Object.fromEntries(dict.flatMap(obj => Object.entries(obj).map((kv) => [kv.join(":"), obj])));` because `translate` goes now from a `O(n)` to a `O(1)` operation. Like this: `function translate(word, from, to) { return dict2[\`${from}:${word}\`]?.[to] ?? word; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get undefined as "from" is not a property of the array object and hence the method could not find any match.

Instead, you can use it in this way:

```
function translate (word, from, to) {
    const translation = dict.find(x => x[from] === word);
    return translation?.[to] ?? word; // returns back the same word if no match is found
}
```